# Segmentation fault linked list in c programming

Tags: c, linked-list

One of the following functions results in a segmentation fault when I run them. To me they look like they should work. I suspect it has something to do with the way I'm using malloc. If anyone can point out which file is producing a error, I would be eternally grateful.

The functions are pretty self explanatory. The first one reads and int from a file and adds a node containing the int to the start of the linked list. The second does the same, but adds the node to the end. The third deletes the third node in a linked list, and the last deletes the last node.

```
LinkedList readAndAddToStart(LinkedList list, FILE *inputFile) {
    LinkedList head;
    head = (LinkedList)malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));
    int num;
    fscanf(inputFile, "%d", &num);
    head->data = num;
    head->next = list;
    return head;
}

LinkedList readAndAddToEnd(LinkedList list, FILE *inputFile) {
    LinkedList addNode;
    addNode = (LinkedList)malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));
    LinkedList head;
    head = list;
    int num;
    fscanf(inputFile, "%d", &num);
    addNode->data = num;
    addNode->next = NULL;
    while (list->next != NULL) {
      list = list->next;
      }
    list->next = addNode;
    return head;
    }

LinkedList deleteFirst(LinkedList list) {
    LinkedList temp;
    temp = list;
    if (list != NULL) {
      list = list->next;
      free(temp);
      temp = NULL;
    }
    return list;
  }
LinkedList deleteLast(LinkedList list) {
    LinkedList head;
    head = list;
    if (list != NULL) {
      while (list->next->next != NULL) {
        list = list->next;
      }
      free(list->next);
      list->next = NULL;
    }
    return head;
  }
```

My struct looks like this BTW

```
struct ListNode {
  int data;                                                
  struct ListNode *next;          
};


typedef struct ListNode *LinkedList;
```

Comment: Use a debugger or better yet valgrind to find your problem.

Comment: Recompile your program with debugging and all compiler warnings enabled. For each warning message you get, fix the root cause. Run it the program with `valgrind`, understand the error messages it prints and fix the root cause. If you get stuck, copy-paste the source code of your entire program (http://sscce.org/) and the full error or warning message to your question, and only then ask for help.

Comment: Please find out which function firstly.It's simple.

Comment: Always check the return value of your I/O function calls (e.g. `fscanf`). At least report the error and make the program exit (`abort()`).

Comment: I was never introduced to any debugging tools, or valgrind, so I'm going to have to look into them. I thought the error was something simple that anyone with decent coding experience should spot. I thought the way I was allocating space using malloc was incorrect or something.

Comment: `head = (LinkedList)malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));` --> `head = (LinkedList)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));` Because `LinkedList` is pointer's type. So `sizeof(LinkedList)` is pointer size, not nod e size. `addNode = (LinkedList)malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));` ditto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`readAndAddToEnd` will crash if `list` is empty.  `deleteLast` will crash if the list has exactly one element.